# Asp.net TextBox Change color

Tags: css, asp.net, controls

if I have asp.net multiline textbox for lets say chatting application. I want every alternate messages background to have 2 diff colors. Like if i type something, the forecolor is black, backcolor is white. If i again type something,, the fore color is still black but the backcolor is grey. Possible folks?
Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your css you can use the sudo class  :nth-child(even) and :nth-child(odd)

```
.message:nth-child(odd) {
    Color:white;
    Background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: So on your asp checkbox use cssClass="message"

Comment: Its a textbox multiline. Still possible? Sorry still learning html

Comment: Should be, as long as it's separate text areas and not one large one

Comment: the example above is obviously not a single large textbox. it is multiple divs with content inside

Comment: Well he didn't post any code, just covering all my bases

Answer (score 0):

Using BackColor Properties

Example

In Page  Load Event 
Textbox1.BackColor=Color.Black

Now Spcified If Condion
Textbox1.BackColor=Color.White